# JavaFX SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, javafx

I recently got an error in my SQL syntax and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
String table = "rfc";
            String update = "UPDATE "+table+" set Type = '" + AWBTypeBox.getValue() + "' set Aantal = " + AWBAantal.getText() + " set Gewicht = " + AWBGewicht.getText() + " set Volume = " + AWBVolume.getText() + " set Beschadiging = '" + AWBBeschadiging.getText() + "' where idReservering = " + account_id + "";
            Statement statement = dbCon.conDatabase().createStatement();

            int resultSet = statement.executeUpdate(update);
```

The error it gives is:

```
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set Aantal = 2 set Gewicht = 20 set Volume = 15 set Beschadiging = 'ja' where id' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

I tried 1 hour trying to change things in the syntax but nothing fixed the error.

Comment: Please look at the [syntax of `UPDATE` in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). It only has **one** `set` clause, and assignments are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

The `set` only occurs once in an `update`:

```
UPDATE "+table+"
    set Type = '" + AWBTypeBox.getValue() + "', 
        Aantal = " + AWBAantal.getText() + ",
        Gewicht = " + AWBGewicht.getText() + ",
        Volume = " + AWBVolume.getText() + ",
        Beschadiging = '" + AWBBeschadiging.getText() + "'
    where idReservering = " + account_id + "";
```

You should replace all but the first `set` with a comma.

The lines are split over multiple rows for clarity.  You should format them as necessary for your application.

Note:  It is also much safer to use parameters in queries.  However, you cannot parameterize a table name, so you still need to put that directly into the string.

Comment: a) you seem to be missing a `"` b) You cannot split string literals over multiple code lines in java...